# Maintaining iphone development/distribution certificates

Tags: iphone, certificate

I am starting to get several certificates for iphone development and need a way to know which is which...

Is there a good way of maintaining these? Can they be renamed appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Just name the files when you create them (the mobile provision files), before you add them to Xcode.  You can rename them in the portal, and you can rename the files when you download them, too.

Comment: This is good for backing up the files, but within the keychain the still appear with more or less the same names

Comment: You should be concerned with how they appear in Xcode, both in the Code Signing section of Build options, and in the Organizer window.